# Перегрузка ModalViewController

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

У меня есть очень простая презентация для iPad из нескольких модальных окон. На каждом View пользователь выполняет простую операцию (например перетягивание слайдера), и после ее выполнения появляется кнопка "Далее" котрая презентует модально (поверх предыдущего) следующий View. С последнего View кнопка ведет на первый, таким образом приложение должно работать рекурсивно. Проблема в том, что начиная со второго раза приложение презентуется в том виде когда уже на всех View функционал выполнен. То есть как сделать так чтобы при переходе с последнего на первый View приложение (все контроллеры) возвращалось к дефолтным настройкам? Можно ли сделать это внутри -prepareForSegue или это более глобальное действие? Если да то как его реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать метод, который все скидывает на дефолт, и из prepareForSegue просто его вызывать. так как там можно достать оба контроллера и обоим подготовить данные.

Comment: Можете более конкретно о методе который все скидывает на дефолт?

Comment: Ну что, типо конечных автоматов. Берем некоторе состояние дефолтное. Т.е. записывае все изначальные координаты всех графических элементов, состояния кнопок анимации. И когда мы находится на данном котроллере мы можем делать все что захотим, так как все его состояния сохранены в приватных переменных. Пишем некий метод, который читает данные из этих переменных и восстанавливает их владельцам, всьюерам, и кнопкам к примеру.
А prepareForSegue имеет входной параметр segue и sender
в нашем случае нас интересует segue но можно и sender в зависимости от логики. 
В общем segue имеет ссылку на контролл

Comment: ер, который имеет наш метод, дефолтного сброса, и все мы его вызываем и segue срабатывает. А что косается sender то там храниться ссылка на только ушедшего котроллера, можно из него вызывать метод сброса состояния и ты всегда будешь заходить сегваем на чистый контроллер.

Comment: Либо как посоветовали ниже, можно трескать область памяти и переиниализировать контроллер заного, тогда уже не надо будет морочиться за состояния.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, проблема в том, что `ModalViewController` создается и присваивает значение `ivar`, как-то так:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ModalDetailViewController *modalViewController;

self.modalViewController = [[ModalDetailViewController alloc] init];
```

поэтому и сохраняется `state`. Если каждый раз при отображении инициировать `ViewController` заново - состояние должно быть дефолтным.
Если же используется что-то типа `popToRootViewController`, то придется, как посоветовали выше, руками устанавливать все контролы в дефолтное состояние в, к примеру, `viewWillAppear`.